# Pivot data based on appearance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am looking to get flag for each service_number for department. For that I have written following PIVOT function but it is not as per my expected output

```
DECLARE @MyTab TABLE 
(
       Service_Number VARCHAR(20),
       Department VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTab VALUES ('12A','ABC'), ('12A','XYZ'), ('12B','ABC'), ('12C','PQR')

SELECT * FROM @MyTab

SELECT   
                                         [ABC],[xyz],[pqr]

              FROM @MyTab
              PIVOT(               MAX(Service_Number)    
              FOR Service_Number IN ([ABC],[xyz],[pqr])) AS P
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Expected output:**

```
Service_Number ABC XYZ PQR
12A            1   1    0
12B            1   0    0
12C            0   1    1
```

Comment: Not FOR Service_Number but FOR Department in (list_of values) , but still will return  1 row, not desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the pivot part as below:

```
SELECT * from
    (Select Service_Number, Department FROM @MyTab ) a
PIVOT( Count(Department) FOR Department IN ([ABC],[xyz],[pqr])) AS P
```

Service_Number does not have [ABC],[xyz]...

Output as below:

```
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| Service_Number | ABC | xyz | pqr |
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 12A            |   1 |   1 |   0 |
| 12B            |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| 12C            |   0 |   0 |   1 |
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+
```